# Is there a way to filter “My Cards” in the Trello widget?

Tags: trello

In the web version of Trello the ["My Cards"](http://help.trello.com/article/819-viewing-all-of-your-cards) page can be filtered to only show cards from specified boards. I use this to filter "My Cards" to show cards from personal boards and hide cards from work boards.

In the Trello widget for Android I can't find a similar filtering option. Is there one? If so how do I get to it?

Comment: I wan't able to find much either .